# Next.JS Fast Refresh not working on Windows (using ubuntu or wsl)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fast-refresh

After changing and saving files using reactJS/Next.JS, the server does not recognize those changes and update itself.

I tried changing various settings per a slew of articles I read, but none worked. Too many things to list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell (run as administrator), type: `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1`.

if this doesn't work and you're using a more specific version of Ubuntu, you can adjust for that: `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 1`, but the key is to use wsl version 1.

I actually found the answer before posting my question, and it was more related to ReactJS, but I wanted to ask this with NextJS to increase visibility, after I spent an hour googling up "nextJS" and the rest of my issue, and getting nothing.

Comment: interesting! I'm using WSL 2 and encountered same issue. Is the only remedy to back to WSL 1?